# Why doesn't splint parse curl/curlbuild.h?

Tags: c, sockets, splint

I wrote a `fornol.c` program that uses the curl library, and therefore includes the following:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
```

I want to run `splint` on my program, but this is the error I get:

```
$ splint fornol.c
Splint 3.1.2 --- 03 May 2009

/usr/include/curl/curlbuild.h:165:33: Parse Error:
    Suspect missing struct or union keyword: socklen_t :
    int. (For help on parse errors, see splint -help parseerrors.)
*** Cannot continue.
```

The suspect line in `curlbuild.h` looks like this:

```
/* Data type definition of curl_socklen_t. */
typedef CURL_TYPEOF_CURL_SOCKLEN_T curl_socklen_t;
```

Where `CURL_TYPEOF_CURL_SOCKLEN_T` has been `#define`d to be `socklen_t`.

**Am I doing something wrong here? What flags should I pass to splint to make it work on my program?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution. Turns out that `sys/socket.h` is not under `/usr/include` on my machine (which I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10).

I had to add the following flag to `splint`:

```
-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

And then it worked.